# How to add a row to a datatable?

Tags: vb.net

I face a stupid problem here. Cannot find an error and do not really know how to fix this.

I'm adding an item into datatable on selected index changed. Everything works, except only the last item is shown in dt. I always has the latest item and all others are gone. i suppose this is because I initialize it in the wrong place but still cannot find a solution.

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Page.Load
        dt.Columns.Add("dr1")
        dt.Columns.Add("dr2")
    End Sub
Protected Sub ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlTest.SelectedIndexChanged
            Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            row(0) = "Test!"
            row(1) ="Test"
            dt.Rows.Add(row)
        End If
    End Sub
```

This always shows only last item in list. How do I do this correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, you create a new DataTable every time a user hits the page.

You need to persist the row to a real database or perhaps make your DataTable shared (static in C#) instead.

```
Shared dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. How can I make my dt static?

Comment: It works now. The question I have though - is it a regular practice to do things like this? Or I better do something else? Is it ok to add columns to a datatable on page load and do it shared? or there's a better approach?

Comment: How do you really want this to work?  You know that when you shut your computer down or restart IIS your data will be lost, right?  Also, all users will share the same state.  Where do you want to store the data?

Comment: This is a temporary storage. The purpose is to allow users to preselect values and then commit them. So I'm storing this in datatable and then show to user all their selection. After they click accepted I submit this things into a database. Do you think that I'm over complicating things?

Comment: And I didn't know that all users will share the same state. Now it is wrong for sure.

Comment: I think ViewState has gone out of favor, but that's the built-in way to make this user-specific.